# Expo Android requests being blocked

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm developing an Expo app on both Android and IOS. I am making the same API request on both IOS and Android but for some reason the Android request is failing.

```
  try {
  const res = await fetch('https://mymarketnews.ams.usda.gov/public_data/ajax-get- 
  commodities/');
  const json = await res.json();
  console.log(json);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

I am recieving the following error on Android:

```
Network request failed
- node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:527:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:135:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:387:16 in callTimers
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:425:19 in __callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:112:6 in 
__guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:373:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:111:4 in 
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I have tried adding an explicit method property on the fetch request as well as some basic headers but nothing seems to work.

Expo version: 3.27.4